# Why does this simple thread code fail?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

I'm trying to make it do that I can't call threads from a loop. But when I run it I get a runtime error:

> `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>
>   what():  Invalid argument 
>   Thread #1`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m;
static int thread_count;

auto foo = [&] {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    std::cout << "Thread #" << ++thread_count << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>>
             threads(20, std::make_shared<std::thread>(foo));

    for (const auto& th : threads)
        th->join();
}
```

Comment: Run it under gdb with `catch throw`.

Comment: @sharth is right. But why the `shared_ptrs`?

Comment: Well, with the code posted as now after the addition of `fill` it is still incorrect. You should be using `std::generate_n`, [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fe79b84205d40c6).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code only actually creates one child thread, and therefore it calls `join()` on that one thread 20 times.

To verify this, you could add the following loop right after you construct the vector:

```
for (int i=1; i<threads.size(); ++i)
    assert(threads[i - 1].get() == threads[i].get());
```

You likely want to create your vector with some form of:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> threads(20);
for (auto & thread : threads)
    thread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(foo);
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz There are many copies of the same shared_ptr in the vector. Or many shared_ptrs managing the same object.

Comment: Ooh, you're right. You should point that out in the answer. The key insight is that `make_shared` is only called once.